# CloudFoundry CLI: Could not load en_US language files

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-plugin

This error randomly appears while the IBM Container executes a shell script that invokes the cf ic commands. Restarting the container appears to fix this problem.

Why am I seeing this?  What is the fix please?

```
cf version 6.12.2-24abed3-2015-07-15T21:21:01+00:00
+++ cf ic group list
+++ grep testgroup1445002343
+++ grep CREATE_COMPLETE
panic: Could not load en_US language files. God save the queen.
mkdir /tmp/cloudfoundry_cli_i18n_res300449142: read-only file system    


goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x87e200, 0xc210070730)
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/i18n.mustLoadDefaultLocale(0x7fc98e5f0990, 0x128aff8)
        /var/vcap/data/gocd-agent/pipelines/Linux64-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/i18n/init.go:105 +0xe8
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/i18n.Init(0x7fc98e5f09c0, 0xc210068d80, 0x7fc98e5f0990, 0x128aff8, 0xc210068d80)
        /var/vcap/data/gocd-agent/pipelines/Linux64-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/i18n/init.go:56 +0x1e4
main.setupDependencies(0x7fc98e46efa0)
        /var/vcap/data/gocd-agent/pipelines/Linux64-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/main/main.go:62 +0x3dd
main.init()
        /var/vcap/data/gocd-agent/pipelines/Linux64-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/main/main.go:31 +0xbd

goroutine 4 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/os/signal/signal_unix.go:21 +0x1e
created by os/signal.init?1
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x31
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Eventually found that for unknown reason I had no /tmp directory on my system (vanished?). I recreated it .... and now it works just fine.